# 2 decimal paces inside input value after click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/55L52yww/98/)

Problems with adding and minus a float number.

So if it starts by 0.2

0.2 + 0.2 = 0.4

0.4 + 0.2 = 0.6000000000000001 (it should be 0.6)

I found that I must use "toFixed(2)" but this is for string? What I msut change in my code in order to make it go normal:

```
// The button to increment the product value
$(document).on('click', '.product_quantity_up', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var arrayData = $(this).data('field-qty');
    var arr = arrayData.split(';');
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        console.log(arr[i]);
    }
    fieldName = arr[0];
    var currentVal = parseFloat($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
    var minimalVal = parseFloat($('input[name='+fieldName+']').attr("data-minimal_quantity"));

    if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal < minimalVal) {
        $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(minimalVal);
        $(this).parent().parent().find(".ajax_add_to_cart_button").attr("data-minimal_quantity",minimalVal);
    }
    else {
        $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + parseFloat(arr[1])).trigger('keyup');
        $(this).parent().parent().find(".ajax_add_to_cart_button").attr("data-minimal_quantity",currentVal + parseFloat(arr[1]));
    }

    $('#'+fieldName).change();



});
```

Comment: You're fiddle has the field as an <input type="text"> so the value would be a string.  Unless I'm misunderstanding your hesitancy to use toFixed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Round to at most 2 decimal places (only if necessary)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary)

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is due to how floating point numbers store information.
If you need to work with an exact number of decimals, I recomend yo work with integers and format the output to reflect the last n positions as decimals.

For example using 2 decimal places, `1.00` is actually `100`.

`0.2 + 0.2 = 0.4` would be done as `20 + 20 = 40`

To print this to the user you parse the integer value to a string and you format the output like `"0.40"` (a string)

Comment: Can you provide an example, please?

Comment: no, that cant be possible for me. the decimal number comes from DB. And there can be different floating number like (1.5, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3)